# Data belonging to one row are showing in multiple rows when a csv file is downloaded using JavaScript and React JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv

I created a custom component in React JS that recieves an array of nested objects, converts it to scv and downloads it upon clicking the button.
Since the data also contains Urdu Characters so I wrote few lines of code to display them as well. Now the values belonging to one row are showing in multiple rows when the csv file is downloaded. Each value is one row down w.r.t to the previous value. I want them to show in the same single row.

I Tried:

```js
const convertToCsv = (data) => {
    const rows = [];

    // Extract headers from the first object in the array
    const headers = Array.from(
      new Set(data.flatMap((item) => Object.keys(item)))
    );

    // Push headers as the first row
    rows.push(headers.join(","));

    // Convert the array of objects to CSV rows
    data.forEach((item) => {
      const row = headers.map((header) => {
        const value = item[header];
        return typeof value === "string"
          ? `"${value.replace(/"/g, '""')}"`
          : value;
      });
      rows.push(row.join(","));
    });

    // Join rows using '\r\n' as a row delimiter
    const csv = "\uFEFF" + rows.join("\r\n");

    return csv;
  };
```

Comment: Could you please share your data too?

Comment: Share your data from the format you are getting and format you as well